# Isotope - Element outside of isotope

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I'm building a page where I have blocks ruled by Isotope, and I'd like to insert a separator.
Here's my example :

```
    <div id="container_iso">
    <div class="block col1"></div>
    <div class="block col2"></div>
    <div class="block col1"></div>
    <div class="block col1"></div>
    <div class="block col1"></div>
    <div class="block col1"></div>
    <div class="block col1"></div>

    <div class="separator"></div>

    <div class="block col1"></div>
    <div class="block col1"></div>
    <div class="block col1"></div>
    <div class="block col1"></div>
    <div class="block col1"></div>
    <div class="block col1"></div>

    <div class="separator"></div>

    </div>
<style>
.container_iso{max-width:999px;}
.block{}
.col1{width:33%;min-width: 333px;}
.col2{width:auto;min-width: 333px;max-width: 666px;}
.separator{width:100%;}
</style>
```

How do I tell Isotope not to work on my "separator" div. That's my js :

```
$('.container_iso').isotope({
      itemSelector : '.block',
      columnWidth : 333,
    });
```

Thank you !

Comment: Ok, in fact my problem is not concerning my separator, in fact my css alows only Isotope to work only if a small block (.col1) first. Don't know why... Do you?

Answer (score 0):

If separator has nothing in it, you can

1) have a transparent png image at its place with your preferred height.
2) you can use this sample code to achieve your target

```
.container_iso{max-width:999px; border: 1px solid #111; }
.block{}
.col1{float: left; width:33%;min-width: 333px;height: 25px; background-color: #eee; border: 1px solid #ddd;}
.col2{float: left; width:auto; min-width: 333px; max-width: 666px; height: 25px; background-color: #ccc; border: 1px solid #ddd;}
.separator{float:left; width:100%; height: 25px; background-color: #fff;}
```

Isotope by default is meant to have no gap in between elements..

If you can jsfiddle the exact scenario, you may get the exact answer.. Here is my jsFiddle as an example:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/C7nUM/3/

http://fiddle.jshell.net/C7nUM/3/show/

Hope that works..

Answer (score 0):

*Based on your followup comment*, your problem is the automatic column sizing.

The default layout is `Masonry`. Masonry calculates positions by allocating a column for each column width across the layout. **It gets the size from the first element if you do not specify it.**

You can however specify the column size in the options. **Important note:** You can actually specify a column width that is smaller than all your items. Best find a value that is a common factor of all your items widths if possible as a very small width results in a more memory use behind the scenes.

### e.g.

```
$('.container_iso').isotope({
      itemSelector : '.block',
      layoutMode: 'masonry',
      masonry: {
          columnWidth: 5
      }
    });
```